# using radio buttons to do some basic maths

Tags: c#

i am making a program that will calculate  how much someone needs to pay if they have had there vehicle parked. I am trying to use radio buttons to select the type of vehicle. when cars(radiobutton1) is selected the algorithm works but when  trucks (radiobutton2)is selected it will not work. here is my code

```
 // cars 
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {



            int hac = Convert.ToInt16(txthrs.Text);
            int h1c = 5;
            int h2c = 3;



            if (txthrs.Text == "1") ;
            money.Text = h1c.ToString();

            if (hac < 1) ;
            money.Text = (h1c + (hac - 1) * h2c).ToString();
            // end of cars 
            // trucks 
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {

                int hat = Convert.ToInt16(txthrs.Text);
                int h1t = 6;
                decimal h2t = 3.5m;



                if (txthrs.Text == "1") ;
                money.Text = h1t.ToString();

                if (hat < 1) ;
                money.Text = (h1t + (hat - 1) * h2t).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is there so when the input box is greater then 1 it will start adding 3 instead of 5 for each hour

Comment: Please show a complete example. You should provide enough code that we can copy it and compile and run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested your if statements, the second if statement will only execute if radio button one is checked. Move the second if block out of the first.

Answer (score 2):

> when trucks (radiobutton2)is selected it will not work.

Firstly, you have some logical mistakes because  `if (hac < 1) ;` and  `(hat < 1) ;` doesn't do anything at all, it's just an expression on its own. With that in mind, i have updated your code to remove those logical errors.

Secondly, don't use `==` to compare `strings`, rather use [`Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Thirdly, the `radioButton2` condition is nested within the `radioButton1` condition hence it causes the unexpected behaviour. You can solve it by separating them like this:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
      int hac = Convert.ToInt16(txthrs.Text);
      int h1c = 5;
      int h2c = 3;

      if (txthrs.Text.ToString().Equals("1")) 
          money.Text = h1c.ToString();

      if (hac < 1) 
          money.Text = (h1c + (hac - 1) * h2c).ToString();
}

if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
     int hat = Convert.ToInt16(txthrs.Text);
     int h1t = 6;
     decimal h2t = 3.5m;

     if (txthrs.Text.ToString().Equals("1")) 
           money.Text = h1t.ToString();
     if (hat < 1) 
           money.Text = (h1t + (hat - 1) * h2t).ToString();

}
```

Comment: You don't need to call ToString on a string (`txthrs.Text.ToString()` and the rest like it are redundant). Second, operator == is overriden for strings so no need to call `Equals()` unless you are passing culture information

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I know, and you're not the first to say "You don't need to call ToString on a string (txthrs.Text.ToString()" and I guess you won't be the last either. As I always say to people, I like to be as explicit as I can when it comes to programming.

Comment: Why stop there then? Surely `myString.ToString().ToString()` is more explicit and will definitely ensure you have a string. If anything it is clutter, as is `if(bool == true)`. To each his own I guess. Btw if you're gonna be explicit, `ToInt16` returns a `short`, you should at least call `ToInt32`, or even better use `int.TryParse` since the data comes from the user (I know that's the OPs code, but point being if you're gonna add in your own ToString calls and recommend changing things that there are better things to point out)